# Como verificar se retorno do Ajax é JSON ou String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string

Meu código está assim:

```
sendAjax(new FormData(this), function(retorno) {
    if(retorno.isArray)
    {
        $(".erro-login strong").text("ID: " + retorno.id + " usuário: " + retorno.usuario);
        $(".erro-login").show("slow");
        navigator.notification.beep(1);
    }
    else
    {
        $("input[name = usuario]").val(retorno);
        $(".erro-login strong").text(retorno);
        $(".erro-login").show("slow");
        navigator.vibrate(1);
    }
});
```

A variável `retorno` pode ser do tipo `String` ou um `Array JSON`, quero saber como diferencio isso no `Jquey`? Tentei usar o `isArray` mas não funcionou, ele continua entrando no `else` com o retorno valendo por exemplo:

```
{
"tipo":1,
"usuario":"Guilherme",
"key":"66bd30f0cf4309c4ad7308fff5efffe8"
}
```

Resumidamente, como diferenciar uma variável quando ela é JSON ou String?

Comment: Qual é o ajax que estás a usar? do jQuery?

Comment: O retorno do backend quse sempre é texto(string) teria que fazer um `retorno = JSON.parse(retorno);` para transforma ela em json 'de verdade'.

Comment: Sim, o `ajax` é do `Jquery`, vou tentar aqui da maneira que o @rray citou.

Comment: @lvcs a resposta aceite é uma boa ferramenta mas para outro tipo de problema. No teu caso se usas jQuery com `dataType: 'json'` como referiste, então recebes sempre um Objeto e o código da resposta aceite dá sempre o mesmo resultado(!)... é isso que queres?

Comment: Eu testei todas respostas com e sem o dataType que no meu caso era indiferente já que eu poderia adicionar ou retirar ele sem prejudicar o restante do código, e a unica resposta que conseguiu ser funcional foi a que eu marquei, as demais não funcionaram nem com o dataType nem sem ele.

Comment: E testaste se esse método dá `true` e `false`? ou dá sempre a mesma resposta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar a função a seguir:

```
function isJson(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

// exemplo de uso
var str = '{'
  + '"tipo":1,'
  + '"usuario":"Guilherme",'
  + '"key":"66bd30f0cf4309c4ad7308fff5efffe8"'
  +'}';

alert(isJson(str));
```

Answer (score 6):

Um JSON passado do servidor para o cliente é uma *String*, um JSON depois de feito *parse*, em JavaScript, é um *Object*. Então se precisas saber se é string ou não basta saber `typeof json == 'string'`. Para teres a certeza podes fazer assim:

```
sendAjax(new FormData(this), function(retorno) {
    if (typeof retorno != 'string') {
        // é Objeto JSON
        // etc...
    } else {
        // é um string, precisa de JSON.parse(json) para ser usado como Objeto
        // etc...
    }
});
```

O jQuery permite passar um parâmetro no objeto de configuração do Ajax para decidir o tipo de dados a receber. Se passares `dataType: 'json'` então podes estar certo que recebes um Objeto.

```
$.ajax(url, {
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    // etc...
```

Comment: Fiz assim, mas de toda forma ele entra no `if(typeof retorno != 'string')`, mesmo o retorno sendo uma string, embora o dataTYpe esteja json

Comment: @lvcs se o `dataType` está JSON então é um objeto, e não uma string. Se estás a usar o Ajax do jQuery com `dataType: 'json'` vais sempre receber um objeto.

Comment: Não sabia desse detalhe do `dataType` +1

Answer (score 0):

O Object.is ainda não é suportado por todos os navegadores, mas você pode fazer um Polyfill para os navegadores que não suportam o ES6, nativamente ele compara dois objetos para verem se são iguais, mas você pode acrescentar ou sobrescreve-los:

```js
var foo = {
  "foo": "foo"
};

Object.is = function(obj) {
  var r = (typeof obj) == 'object' ? true : false;
  return r;
};


console.log(Object.is(foo));
```

Comment: Acho que esta resposta (e a resposta aceite) respondem a outra coisa do que o problema da pergunta. O AP refere _"o ajax é do Jquery"_ e que o `dataType` está `json`. Por isso ele recebe sempre um Objeto.